# LokiJs collection find return list in Ascending order

Tags: sorting, lokijs

How do i get to sort a  loki js collection in a ascending order

```
var categoryCollection = offlineDb.getCollection('Category');
var catColl = categoryCollection.find({ 'Id': { '$ne': null } });
```

I debug and i see that the $loki is also in the reverse order .
This returns the list in a reverse order ! How can i perform a find with the list in ascending order ? Isnt it by default when you do a find return in a ascending order ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two ways of sorting the result: either by passing your own sorting function in `sort(fun)`, or using `simplesort(property [, isdesc])` the second parameter being the ascending/descending order flag. See [here](http://techfort.github.io/LokiJS/Resultset.html)

Comment: Thanks. Any particular reason that the find returns the collection in a descending order ? Or is there any place globally that can set for all collections to find in the ascending order?

Comment: as an in-memory database, the idea is that you use LokiJS as a local cache or interface for a traditional db, so in a way most recent records are usually more relevant. Having said that, I don't remember why we decided to make descending the default sort. Unfortunately no, there is no way to globally make all resultset sorted in ascending oreder.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the great product - your DB rocks!  BTW still not easy to google out http://lokijs.org/ thus the Github comes up first

Answer (score 1):

Note that `simplesort()` requires `chain()`, which returns a `ResultSet` instead of a standard `Array`:

```
categoryCollection.chain().find({ 'Id': { '$ne': null } }).simplesort('Id');
```

If you just need the `Array` with a flipped order, use `Array.reverse()`:

```
categoryCollection.find({ 'Id': { '$ne': null } }).reverse();
```

If `reverse()` still isn't enough to sort the data, use a `chain(), simplesort(), data()` sandwich to return a standard Array:

```
categoryCollection.chain().find({ 'Id': { '$ne': null } }).simplesort('Id').data();
```